# Typescript - how to enforce fallback for empty object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have below code

```
interface Data {
 news: News
}
```

Since data is fetched from the api, at first it will be `undefined`, after loading the result is fetched.

Therefore, below code will break the app on Run time.

App.tsx

```
const { news } = data;
```

Because of

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'news' of undefined
```

Until I update the code to

```
const { news } = data??{};
```

Now the question is, is it possible to enforce the pattern `const { news } = data??{};`, e.g. by Eslint, so that I can prevent the error happens on run time? Or is there another way to handle it?

The reason I want to do it, because it happens after deployment, so I wanna check if there is a way to prevent it happens again

Comment: How is data defined? If it's with a `useState`, just set the default value to an empty object.

Comment: enable `strictNullChecks` in tsconfig should help

Comment: This tells me you've defined the type of `data` incorrectly. If it can potentially be `undefined` then it should be defined like as e.g. `Data|undefined`

Comment: You can use [one of these patterns](https://tsplay.dev/w22gbw). Does that answer your question? If so, I can write it up as one — if not, what am I still missing?

Answer (score 0):

If `data` in `const { news } = data;` is of type `Data | undefined`, then TypeScript won't compile, preventing that runtime error, while `const { news } = data??{};` would compile. I believe this is the best way to enforce it in TypeScript.